# Time range filter is not working for Bar-chart and Bar-gauge in Grafana

Tags: time, range, grafana, selector

```
*We are trying to utilize the time range selector in grafana which works only for time series representation as of now. Can you please let me know any way to utilize that time range selector for bar-chart and bar-graph in Grafana representation.*
```

Adding the Schema, query and representation in grafana for reference.

1. Schema:[ https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2srW.png]
2. query: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwWRJ.png]
3. Bar-chart rep: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MQbA.png]

Answer (score 1):

Not totally sure what you are asking but hopefully this is right.

Your query has no where clause to filter by the selected time in Grafana. You can use a Grafana macro to add a time range filter. [The MySQL macro documentation is here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/mysql/#macros). And there are some examples further down on the page.

You haven't specified what the table schema looks like or which column you want to use for filtering. So I made a guess and just added a where clause with the `$__timeFilter` macro and filtering on the `lastupdated` column as it is the only datetime column in your example:

```
SELECT
  lastupdated as time_sec,
  TIME_FORMAT(sec_to_time(time), "%H:%i") AS total_time,
  mrid as metric
  ,time/3600 as time_in_hours
FROM margetomerge.mergedetails
WHERE $__timeFilter(lastupdated)
order by mrid desc
```